# Configure not recognized

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to make a number generator yet I ran into a problem. It doesn't recognize configure. I am kind of new to tkinter and with my beginner knowledge with python, it really made my head scratching. This is the code:

```
from tkinter import messagebox
import random
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

window = Tk()
window.title("Random Number Generator")
window.geometry('350x200')

title_lbl = Label(window, text="Press the button to generate!").grid(row=0, column=1)

def rannum():
    ran = random.randint(0, 10000000)
    com = ans_lbl.configure(text=ran)
    
    
btn = Button(window, text='Randomize', command=rannum).grid(row=1, column=0)

ans_lbl = Label(window, text='').grid(row=2, column=0)

window.mainloop()
```

This is the error I recieved :

```
File "C:\Users\(redacted)\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1921, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "c:\Users\(redacted)\Documents\(redacted)\(redacted)", line 15, in rannum
    com = ans_lbl.configure(text=ran)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'configure'
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8949252/why-do-i-get-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-something Does this help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ans_lbl is being assigned the value `None` because when you initialized it you set it to the value of Label.grid(). What you want to do is separate the Label() and .grid() calls.

Replace

`ans_lbl = Label(...).grid(...)`

With this:

`ans_lbl = Label(...)`

`ans_lbl.grid(...)`

I've done this below, and moved the initialization of ans_lbl up beside title_lbl for readability.

```
import random
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

window = Tk()
window.title("Random Number Generator")
window.geometry('350x200')

title_lbl = Label(window, text="Press the button to generate!").grid(row=0, column=1)
ans_lbl = Label(window, text='')
ans_lbl.grid(row=2, column=0)

def rannum():
    ran = random.randint(0, 10000000)
    com = ans_lbl.configure(text=ran)


btn = Button(window, text='Randomize', command=rannum).grid(row=1, column=0)


window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score -1):

Can you change your method to this and try once.

```
def rannum():
    ran = random.randint(0, 10000000)
    # com = ans_lbl.configure(text=ran)
    ans_lbl = Label(window, text=ran).grid(row=2, column=0)
```

Comment: You are creating new label each time instead of changing the existing label